# How can I send a POST request without any payload using restTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, rest, http-post, resttemplate

I need to trigger a POST request using rest template. But the problem is this request don't have any body. I tried invoking it from POSTMAN it was successful. Attaching the postman related screenshots below

[image: Request Header]

[image: Request Body]

The same API I need to trigger through rest template. But It is giving Bad request exception with the following piece of code

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + "<token>");
headers.set("Content-Length", "0");
HttpEntity<Map<?, ?>> entity = new HttpEntity<Map<?, ?>>(null, headers);
ResponseEntity<E> response = null;
try {
    response = restTemplate.exchange(api, methodType, entity, type);
```

> nb: Instead of null. I also tried giving an empty map as body. But
> that too didn't work for me.

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Can you add the error message?

Answer (score 0):

try this way :
HttpEntity<Map> entity = new HttpEntity<Map>(new Map<null,null>, headers);